# Ios memory management comes out so confused: CFGetRetainCount()

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, dynamic-arrays, retaincount

In ARC environment, I allocate a dynamic array of which each element is a pointer to NSObject*. Then use CFGetRetainCount to get the retain count of the NSObject. The result comes out as expected. However, when I change the NSObject to NSString, the retain count comes out as a large number, which confused me so much. I have searched google, but can't find any valuable information. So, can anyone explain? Appreciate any help.

first code snippet:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSObject* __strong *arr = nil;
        arr = (id __strong *)calloc(2, sizeof(id));
        *arr = [[NSObject alloc]init];
        *(arr + 1) = [[NSObject alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"--->retainCount:%lu -->%@", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)*arr), *arr);
        //output:--->retainCount:1 --><NSObject: 0x100103a00>
        *arr = nil;
        *(arr + 1) = nil;
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

second code snippet:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* __strong *arr = nil;
        arr = (id __strong *)calloc(2, sizeof(id));
        *arr = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"str_01"];
        *(arr + 1) = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"--->retainCount:%lu \n-->%@", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)*arr), *arr);
        //output:--->retainCount:1152921504606846975 -->str_01
        *arr = nil;
        *(arr + 1) = nil;
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the NSLog outputs confuse me:
why the retain count is not "1" in the second code snippet? is there any different compared with the first code snippet?

Comment: `NSString` has lots of optimizations regarding its memory management.  Your string is probably actually a tagged pointer.

Comment: but when i chage the NSString to other Objects, such as NSArray, the retain count also a huge number.

Comment: Other objects also have optimizations regarding their memory management.  The initializer for for an empty `NSArray` probably returns a singleton instance.

Comment: NSObject is super for all Object types, you mean there's no optimizations for NSObject? That's odds. And the NSString with retain count 1152921504606846975, why for that? What's the scene behind that?

Comment: `NSTaggedPointerString` returns `2^64` from its `retainCount` method.  I think you're losing some bits when bridging it since `retainCount` returns an unsigned value while `CFGetRetainCount` returns a signed value so you end up with that number.

Comment: @blueGhost CFRetainCount() is every bit as useless as -retainCount.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that several Foundation classes in Objective C - like `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSNumber` - don't behave like "normal" user classes. For example, `NSNumber` is typically a so-called tagged pointer - a pointer at a "illegal" address (which is not divisible by 4 or 8) and represents the value and not an address. `NSString`, `NSArray`... are implemented as so-called class clusters, which is a mechanism that exchanges the internal implementation inside the initializer (e.g. returns a different object than the one that was allocated by the `alloc` call). Most often, `NSString`s are interned / atomized, which is a way to allow quick comparisons etc. by simple pointer comparision (instead of `strncmp`-like byte-by-byte comparisons).

To fall a long story short: You should never rely on retain counts, this is just an implementation detail of the reference counting mechanism.

Comment: Some objects reside at addresses divisible by 2, btw.